# Snowflake JDBC Connection timeout with proxy

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, proxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, web-application-firewall

We have an java web application deployed in windows server 2019 VM with tomcat 9.0.37 , this VM is heavily firewalled and works only with proxy.
The existing web app deployed in tomcat connects with Snowflake using proxy settings in the end of  JDBC Url:

```
jdbc:snowflake://xxxxx.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/?db=xxxxx&useProxy=true&proxyHost=xxx.xxx.com&proxyPort=8080
```

This works perfect.
Now in that same tomcat when we deploying a new beta version of the same application separately , and using exact same jdbc URL and JDBC props(Verified multiple times by comparing side by side), its doing long wait and showing Gateway Timeout error , in logs :

```
30-Jun-2021 10:59:15.909 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest.execute Stop retrying since elapsed time due to network issues has reached timeout. Elapsed=84,011(ms), timeout=60,000(ms)
```

There is no code changes in the new beta version regarding Snowflake connectivity. Its exactly the same. And the JDBC Jar version in both application is also exactly same. Even we tried with same application context name , still it showing same thing. We tried with multiple snowflake accounts , all working with proxy in the old application , nothing works with proxy in the new beta application.

We tried **SnowCD** Network Diagonistic tool , it works good with same proxy settings passed as command line argument.
Snowcd With Proxy    = Passed 13 out out of 13 checks
Snowcd Without Proxy = Failed 27 out out of 27 checks

What next we can do here , please suggest any other troubleshooting to find the root cause.

**Note**: The same new beta version working fine with snowflake connectivity with every other developer and testing team who using it in normal environment without proxy/firewall including myself.

Comment: This might sound silly and also not sure of your timezone but around 18:30 UTC yesterday, Snowflake had an outage with some customers not being able to connect. The issue was resolved a few hours later. Have you tried connecting today? We were not affected and Snowflake didn't say what setups were having trouble so perhaps proxy connections were?

Comment: @DeanFlinter Not the case , we trying to fix this from last 10 days

Comment: Fair enough! Assume this is running in some sort of Dev or staging environment? Sounds like the proxy/firewall may be configured differently in this environment. Maybe ask your networking team to double check? I realise that's not much help but sometimes it's an simple thing that was overlooked